# UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns nil more than once

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my test on the device and in simulator, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: returns nil more than once (about 5 times for a table with 15 rows). Is this normal? I was under impression it should return nil ***only*** the very first time?

Comment: I think you may misunderstand the purpose of method. I am not sure why you would care how many times it returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tableView and collectionView have limits. If you scroll fast enough, or there are a lot of elements on that cell (takes longer to prepare), iOS may not prepare the reusable cell as fast as the cellForIndexPath is getting called.

So in the case of tableView, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil.
And in the case of CollectionView `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will create a new object for you.

Answer (score 3):

The `UITableView` class implements the behaviour of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. As long as you're calling it in the right place (i.e. inside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) then there's not much you can do about it returning or not returning reusable cells.

It's not something I'd worry about unless I could prove that specific behaviour was giving me crashes or performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

The table view handles cells using the fly weight pattern. If you familiarize yourself with that you will have a better grasp of what is happening and why.